# Jquery AJAX beforeSend function fails IE 8

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, internet-explorer

Im new to jquery and I am stuck. This page works perfectly in Firefox and Chrome but at the beforeSend function in IE8 I always get "All Fields are required" no matter what I do. Can someone point out to me what IE is doing to always cause this function to fail? Thanks.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Contact form</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<link href="../css/modal_company.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
function getQueryParams(qs) {
    qs = qs.split("+").join(" ");
    var params = {},
        tokens,
        re = /[?&]?([^=]+)=([^&]*)/g;
    while (tokens = re.exec(qs)) {
        params[decodeURIComponent(tokens[1])]
            = decodeURIComponent(tokens[2]);
    }
    return params;
}
var $_GET = getQueryParams(document.location.search);
var holy = $_GET["strUser"] 
document.getElementById('hide').value = holy;
    $('#submit_button').click(function() { 
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'item_add.php',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function() {
                var item_num = $('#item_num').val();
                var descript = $('#descript').val();
                var quanti = $('#quanti').val();
                var fdaa = $('#fdaa').val();                
                if (!item_num[0] ||  !descript[0] || !quanti[0] || !fdaa[0]) { 
                    $('#output').html('All fields are required');
                    return false; 
                }                
            },
            success: function(response) {
                if (response.status == 'success') {
                    $('#formcont').html();
                }
                $('#output').html(response.errmessage);
            }
        });        
    });
}); 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="formcont" style="text-align:center; margin:0; padding:0; height:100%;">
  <form id="myform">
    <fieldset>
      <div style="text-align:center; margin-bottom:20px; border-bottom:thin #000; width:100%;">
        <h2>Add an Item</h2>
      </div>
      <p>
        <label for="hide"><strong>Manufacturer:</strong></label>
        <input type="text" readonly name="hide" id="hide" size="30" value="" style="background-color:#CCC" />
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="item_num"><strong>Item / Catalog #:</strong></label>
        <input type="text" name="item_num" id="item_num" size="30" />
      </p>

      <p>
        <label for="descript"><strong>Description:</strong></label>
        <input type="text" name="descript" id="descript" size="30" />
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="quanti"><strong>Quantity Per Unit:</strong></label>
        <input type="text" name="quanti" id="quanti" size="30" />
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="fdaa"><strong>Is this Item FDA Approved?</strong></label>
        <input type="text" name="fdaa" id="fdaa" size="30" />
      </p>      
    </fieldset>
    <div id="output" style="width:100%; color:red; text-align:center;"></div>
     <div style="text-align:center; margin-bottom:0px; border-bottom:thin #000; width:100%; margin-left:105px;">
        <p style="text-align:center;">
      <input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit_button" />
    </p>
      </div> 
  </form>
</div>
<div id="output"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Note: If I remove that function then everything works great in IE. It submits to the database and gives me the success messages I'm looking for. Not sure what it is about this function.

Comment: What is the purpose of doing `[0]` on strings? It's not even supported by IE7 for example.

Comment: It was there in the original code I was working from and it worked so I didn't touch it. Could that be the problem? It works fine in Firefox and Chrome as is.

Comment: Just try `!item_num ||  !descript || !quanti || !fdaa` ... I have a hunch that your ie8 version doesn't support string subscript notation :P (Mine does but I am running in IE9 compatibility mode) The code will effectively be the same - It will pass the if condition if any of the variables was an empty string.

Comment: Thanks a ton Esailija. I removed the [0] and it works great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your validation part as follows.

```
if (item_num == '' ||  descript == '' || quanti == '' || fdaa == '') { 
  $('#output').html('All fields are required');
  return false; 
}
```

there is not need of using [0] for the strings.

Answer (score -1):

success is called on correct execute (i.e. status `4` OR status `"complete"`). Use the error for error handling...

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'item_add.php',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function() {
            var item_num = $('#item_num').val();
            var descript = $('#descript').val();
            var quanti = $('#quanti').val();
            var fdaa = $('#fdaa').val();                
            if (!item_num[0] ||  !descript[0] || !quanti[0] || !fdaa[0]) { 
                $('#output').html('All fields are required');
                return false; 
            }                
        },
        success: function(response) {
            ...
            $('#formcont').html();
            ...
        },
        error: function(status, errorText) {
            ...
            $('#output').html(response.errorText);
            ...
        }
});
```

In other cases when you seek more control on a lower level you can use:

```
complete(jqXHR, textStatus)
```

as follows...

```
...
complete: function(req, status) {
    ..
    ..
}
...
```